SOL sent through Coinbase not showing up in Phantom Wallet
I sent SOL from Coinbase to my Phantom Wallet around two days ago and it’s yet to show up. Coinbase says the transaction was successful and yes I sent it to the right address.
Here’s the transaction address: 37YeGRJ4UV59FLTyALB5yVgxo3mNADAcquNcEVHunfrPBHSK7dQ5eT7LGDticjR9tWuvugeBG17M4WJnExAfK7r9


You already got sol balance in your wallet.
As you can see, I can show your balance in my phantom wallet with watch account.
Please check your network status

Nvm I sent it to the wrong wallet  Lesson learned

You are welcome.
